# how do we know the first 4 bytes read on a tcp socket are the length of the message?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

The ["Sending and receiving logging events across a network"](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) section of the python logging cookbook demonstrates how a clients can send logs via a TCP session.

Log messages are pickled and sent to the server thanks to the [socket handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SocketHandler). The server then unpickle the messages and log them.

The code to get a message from the tcp socket is this one:

```
class LogRecordStreamHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    """Handler for a streaming logging request.

    This basically logs the record using whatever logging policy is
    configured locally.
    """

    def handle(self):
        """
        Handle multiple requests - each expected to be a 4-byte length,
        followed by the LogRecord in pickle format. Logs the record
        according to whatever policy is configured locally.
        """
        while True:
            chunk = self.connection.recv(4)
            if len(chunk) < 4:
                break
            slen = struct.unpack('>L', chunk)[0]
            chunk = self.connection.recv(slen)
            while len(chunk) < slen:
                chunk = chunk + self.connection.recv(slen - len(chunk))
            obj = self.unPickle(chunk)
            record = logging.makeLogRecord(obj)
            self.handleLogRecord(record)

    # then, methods to handle the record, but that's not the interesting part


class LogRecordSocketReceiver(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    """
    Simple TCP socket-based logging receiver suitable for testing.
    """

    allow_reuse_address = 1

    def __init__(self, host='localhost',
                 port=logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT,
                 handler=LogRecordStreamHandler):
        SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), handler)
        self.abort = 0
        self.timeout = 1
        self.logname = None

    def serve_until_stopped(self):
        import select
        abort = 0
        while not abort:
            rd, wr, ex = select.select([self.socket.fileno()], [], [], self.timeout)
            if rd:
                self.handle_request()
            abort = self.abort
```

What I don't understand in this example is: how do we know that the first 4 bytes we read from the socket constitute the length of the message? I looked at the `socket`, and `logging` documentation but could not find mention of it.

Also, the docstring implicitly states that this code is not good enough for production. What is so bad about that code?

Comment: Examine the sending code.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks, I'll post the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the answer is in the sending code (handlers.py in python 2.7.10). I just removed the docstrings/comments that were obvious or irrelevant to this question to make the code more readable.

```
def makePickle(self, record):
    ei = record.exc_info
    if ei:
        dummy = self.format(record)
        record.exc_info = None
    d = dict(record.__dict__)
    d['msg'] = record.getMessage()
    d['args'] = None
    s = cPickle.dumps(d, 1)
    if ei:
        record.exc_info = ei

    # slen represents a "long integer", which is usually 32 bits large.
    slen = struct.pack(">L", len(s))

    # Here is where the 4 byte length is prepended to the message
    return slen + s


def emit(self, record):
    try:
        s = self.makePickle(record)
        # s is actually (length of the message) + (message)
        self.send(s)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except:
        self.handleError(record)



def send(self, s):
    """
    Send a pickled string to the socket.

    This function allows for partial sends which can happen when the
    network is busy.
    """
    if self.sock is None:
        self.createSocket()

    if self.sock:
        try:
            if hasattr(self.sock, "sendall"):
                self.sock.sendall(s)
            else:
                sentsofar = 0
                left = len(s)
                while left > 0:
                    sent = self.sock.send(s[sentsofar:])
                    sentsofar = sentsofar + sent
                    left = left - sent
        except socket.error:
            self.sock.close()
            self.sock = None  # so we can call createSocket next time
```